# Task similar to happy number

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am solving a c++ algorithmic problem and I don't know why I don't get a right answer. The problem consists in : there is given a row of n numbers. The you need to take each number and add the square of its digits till you get the sum 4 or 1. Then you need to print how many times you have added that number. His is an example: you have a row of 2 numbers: 89 and 68. You start with 89:
64 + 81 = 145;(1) 1 + 16 + 25 = 42;(2) 16 + 4 = 20;(3) 4 + 0 = 4;(4)
and we stop because it is 4. We need to print 4 because we added 4 times again and again till we got 4 or 1.The same with 68. My code is in c++ but it uses for files c.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

FILE *f,*g;
int n,i,a[500],sqr,nr;
int main()
{
  f = fopen("unupatru.in","r");
  fscanf(f,"%d\n",&n);
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)fscanf(f,"%d",&a[i]);
  fclose(f);
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
    nr=0;
    sqr=0;
    while(sqr!=4 || sqr !=1)
    {
      while(a[i])
      {
        sqr+=pow(a[i]%10,2);
        a[i]/=10;
      }
      a[i]=sqr;
      nr++;
    }  
    g=fopen("unupatru.out", "w");
    fprintf(g,"%d\n",nr);
    fclose(g);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Please help me
The problem with my code is that when I click on run and compile it doesn't stop running please help

Comment: You're using the wrong headers; you need e.g. `<cstdio>`.

Comment: If you're using C++, first remove calls to C functions

Comment: Thanks for the sugestions, but the problem is not in this thing, I have been solving problems like that for a week and it wasn't a problem, the problem is something with the logic of the code, please let it like, tell me better how to fix it, the code is really similar to c

Comment: `while(sqr!=4 || sqr !=1)` This condition is always true, your loop never stops. `sqr` can't be 4 and 1 at the same time.

Comment: but it should not be 4 and 1, the || operator means or, so if it will be 4 or 1 it will stop not 4 and 1

Comment: It will continue while `sqr!=4 || sqr !=1` is true, ends when `sqr!=4 || sqr !=1` is false. `sqr!=4 || sqr !=1` will be false when `!(sqr!=4 || sqr !=1)` will be true, so when `sqr==4 && sqr  ==1` will be true, which will never happen. See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure is enough but...

You should put `sqr = 0` also inside the external while and (as pointed by Igor Tandetnik) modify the test using `&&` instead `||`

Or better: you shuold use `do`/`while` (with `sqr=0` only inside)

```
do
{
  sqr=0;
  while(a[i])
  {
    sqr+=pow(a[i]%10,2);
    a[i]/=10;
  }
  a[i]=sqr;
  nr++;
} 
while(sqr!=4 && sqr !=1)
```

Comment: Thanks you solved the problem that I had, but I don't get the write answer

Comment: @MelinVen - sorry: I mean: you should **add** `sqrt=0` inside the while maintaining the `sqr=0` outside; maybe `do`/`while` is better.

Comment: may be you have an idea how to make this problem give me the right answer?

Comment: but just for the second one, about the first opne it forgot

Comment: Done thanks everyone, I solved the whole problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
FILE *f,*g;
int n,i,a[500],sqr,nr,b[500];
int main()
{
  f = fopen("unupatru.in","r");
  fscanf(f,"%d\n",&n);
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)fscanf(f,"%d",&a[i]);
  fclose(f);
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
         nr=0;
         sqr=0;
      while(sqr!=4 && sqr !=1)
       {
           sqr=0;
           while(a[i])
            {
               sqr+=pow(a[i]%10,2);
               a[i]/=10;
            }
              a[i]=sqr;
              nr++;
              b[i]=nr;
       } 
  }

      g=fopen("unupatru.out", "w");
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      fprintf(g,"%d ",b[i]);
      fclose(g);
  return 0;
```

}